# Command or environment that forces math text to be put on italics

Tags: environments, italic

Being as straight forward as I can, I want to create a command or an environment that forces `\mathit` within it. For example:

```
\begin{turnmathit}Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Then $x + y$ is also a real number.\end{turnmathit}
```

I wanted the whole text above to become italic (text and math) with this hypothetical `turnmathit` environment (or maybe just a command, whichever is easier to handle). Any tips or solutions you guys know? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Would text italics be OK for the text (non-math) part of the `turnmathit` environment, or does it have to be *math* italics too? (TeX's math italic mode automatically gobbles spaces, including all interword spaces. That would make the text rather hard to read, wouldn't it?)

Comment: Is your query a variation of your earlier, [Italic environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297645/5001), posting?

Comment: In this case I ask specifically for a command and/or an environment and make a MWE, kind of. Sorry if it sounded ambiguos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the whole text to become italic (text and math).

The `\emph` directive may be what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\emph{Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Then $x + y$ is also a real number.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this a case where `\textit` is more appropriate than `\emph`?

Comment: @gernot -- For sure, `\textit` wouldn't be *wrong*. :-) What's *more appropriate* -- `\textit` or `\emph` -- depends crucially on the OP's use case, about which we know next to nothing so far. If the objective is "render the material in italics, no matter what", then `\textit` would certainly be the way to go. If the objective is a bit broader, say, "emphasize the material", then `\emph` would be better since it is context-sensitive, in the sense that it distinguishes between "outer" and "inner" mode. I had interpreted the OP's query as leaning towards the "emphasize the material" direction.

Comment: Sorry for being so clearless: I'm typing questions for a book, and right below there'll be the answers. So, I want the whole question text to be in italics and the answers in regular text. And @Mico , I think I've found the problem: since I haven't provided a decent MWE, there would be no way for you to know that I also use the ```euler``` family font on my math texts. Thing is, it has no italics family on it. When I use ```mathit``` what it does is bring it back to basic CM, I guess. Is there a way to change the math font inside ```emph```?

Comment: @ItaloMarinho - I'm not sure I understand your setup. I thought that `euler` is a math-only font package -- not text component at all. (And, `euler` glyphs are upright by design, not slanted/italic.) Generally, one pairs the `euler` math font with a text font such as `Palatino`. Or, if one wants to emulate the look of the `Concrete Mathematics` textbook, one could use the `Concrete` text font. Are you looking to replace the `euler` math font with a slanted font in the emphasized parts? It would help very much if you edited your posting to state your document in (much) greater detail.

Comment: There's not much else than that. It's exactly as you said: replace ```euler``` math font  with a slanted font within emphasized parts. .

Comment: Well, if you want to switch math fonts within a document, you'll need to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Are you doing so already?

Comment: @user202729 - Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't seem to work with numbers".

Comment: @Mico Actually... never mind. (to make all text \textit and all math \mathit there's the OP 's other question. I don't really get why the OP accept this answer *or* what OP intended for this question to be different from the other.)